# Handler PostDelayed method runs faster than 1 second when given a delay of 1 second

Tags: java, android

I have a `Handler` `postDelayed` method, i have passed 1 second of delay and calling it again and again. I am also printing the seconds passed every second, but what i am observing is that it prints faster than 1 second. So in a second, its printing 2-3 seconds.

This is the code:

```js
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Timer running...");
        if (startCounter) {
          timeCheck -= 1000;
          //check if device is connected every second
          //if it is connected then reset timer
          Log.d(TAG, "Time: " + timeCheck / 1000 + " sec");
          if (Constants.IS_CONNECTED) {
            timeCheck = 180000;
            updateFlutter(1);
            Log.d(TAG, "Device is connected");
          } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected but might be in sleep mode");
            if (timeCheck <= 0) {
              //                            not connecting
              //                            device has been disconnected
              Log.d(TAG, "Fully Disconnected");
              updateFlutter(0);
              startCounter = false;
              mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
        h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
      }
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood the problem, so basically what was happening is that a new thread was being called everytime the `startTimer` method was being called. Now `multiple threads` were trying to decrease the value of `timeCheck`, and hence time was passing way fast than it should have. For this to resolve, i changed the `global` variable to `local` variable and it solved the problem for me.